# What does "{% %}" syntax mean?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using someones PHP file.
And it has text like:

```
<html>
... regular HTML
{% if (some condition){       
    <another regular html tag>
    </another regular html tag>
}%}
</html>
```

And I don't get it if these {% tags %} are javascript or PHP, or something else?
thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is some templating language. Most likely a server-side one, i.e. one that is based on PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a template to me. The `{%` and `%}` is the templating's system of identifying where it has to do its work.

Answer (score 1):

It can think of two reasons:

1. User might have changed `"<?" to "<%"`
2. It is a template language