# what does {% %} mean in html

Tags: php, html

I think it's used to reference php stuff, but I'm not sure. I see some of it written like this in the html file:

```
{% if ban.reason %}
    <p class="reason">
        {{ ban.reason }}
    </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it could be a django template, or smarty template

Comment: This question doesn't deserves the close vote. It's a perfect question and it can help beginners.

Comment: code between {% %} is an php expression and code between {{ }} is an output. {{ban.reason}} can be <?php echo $ban["reason"] ?> or sth else. You better figure out what template engine is being used in. Please read Twig template engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "{% %}" syntax mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262195/what-does-syntax-mean)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a **Template Engine** system, and its syntax is based on [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). Another code example:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
            <li><a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

*from wikipedia:*

#### Benefits of using template engines include:

- Encouraging organization of source code into operationally-distinct layers (see e.g., MVC)
- Enhancing productivity by reducing unnecessary reproduction of effort
- Enhancing teamwork by allowing separation of work based on skill-set (e.g., artistic vs. technical)

#### Typical features

Template engines typically include features common to most high-level programming languages, with an emphasis on features for processing plain text.
Such features include:

- variables and functions
- text replacement
- file inclusion (or transclusion)
- conditional evaluation and loops

*(end from wikipedia)*

---

There are a several template engines for PHP.
One of them is [**Twig**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

For example instead of writing such this:

```
<?php echo $var ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
```

You can do this with Twig:

```
{{ var }}
{{ var|escape }}
```

And another example:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <?php if (navigation) { ?>
        <?php foreach ($navigation as $item) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $item->href; ?>"><?php echo $item->caption; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

In template engine:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    {% for item in navigation %}
        <li><a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.caption }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

It could be also **Javascript Template** like [blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates). Another code example:

```
<title>{%=o.title%}</title>
<h3><a href="{%=o.url%}">{%=o.title%}</a></h3>
<h4>Features</h4>
<ul>
{% for (var i=0; i<o.features.length; i++) { %}
    <li>{%=o.features[i]%}</li>
{% } %}
</ul>
```

"o" (the lowercase letter) is a reference to the data parameter of the template function.

Answer (score 5):

This syntax is used by a template engine that reads this file and generates the final HTML.
Some of them may be Django or Smarty like @karthikr commented.